# running script in google sheets and getting #num! error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hey im trying to create a code in script in google sheets that but im getting #NUM! error all the time.

```
    function Trador() {
  var app =SpreadsheetApp;
  var activesheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var targetsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("End");
  var data = targetsheet.getLastRow();
  targetsheet.getRange(11,10).setValue(data);

  var strike;
  var outcome;
  var checkstrike;
  var openintrest;

  for (var c=2;c<=data;c++){
    stike = targetsheet.getRange(c,3).getValue();
    outcome = 0;
    for (var b=2;b<=data;b++){
      checkstrike = targetsheet.getRange(b,3).getValue();
      if (strike>checkstrike){
        openintrest = targetsheet.getRange(b,2).getValue(); // call
        if (openintrest='-'){
          openintrest=0;
        }
        outcome = (strike-checkstrike) * 100 * openintrest + outcome;
      } else{
        openintrest = targetsheet.getRange(b,5).getValue(); // put
        if (openintrest='-'){
          openintrest=0;
        }
        outcome = (checkstrike-strike) * 100 * openintrest + outcome;
      }
    }
    targetsheet.getRange(c,9).setValue(outcome);

  }
}
```

this is the code i have.
I know that probbably i didnt explained my self to the full but i simply dont know how to describe what it is that im trying to do  LOL.

i would really appreciate any help i can get!
thank you in advance!

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(outcome)` before using `setValue`. What does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best if you can identify the line the error occurs. Remember, the debugger is you friend. I spotted this mistake

```
if (openintrest='-'){
  openintrest=0;
}
```

This is assigning a dash to the variable, not comparing. Try this:

```
if (openintrest == '-'){
  openintrest=0;
}
```

This occurs twice in the script.

Also, another variable typo

```
stike = targetsheet.getRange(c,3).getValue();
```

Suppose to be

```
strike = targetsheet.getRange(c,3).getValue();
```

The cool thing is Google updated the script editor recently so it can autocomplete as we type also shows variables not used differently as well.

[image]

In this case activesheet is not used.

Comment: thank you that work! didnt noticed i had a typo!!!!
went over this for hours XD

Comment: lol, those gremlins bite me every now and then as well. Variables are case sensitive as well, most use camelCase notation for consistency.